# Unity DllImport fails with .so libraries

Tags: unity-game-engine, shared-libraries, dllimport, tizen

I'm using Unity 5.3.4p1 together with the Tizen SDK 2.4.0Rev5.
I'm trying to develop a very simple native plugin, following carefully [the Unity guide](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForTizen.html), and everything seems fine.

I get my Shared Object library (.so file, beginning with "lib"), place it in `Assets/Plugins/Tizen/libs`, build it, install to the device, and everything seems fine.

Then, I play my build and...

```
I/Unity   (18506): Couldn't open /opt/usr/apps/com.myStubCompany.testTizen/lib/libtizennative.so, error: /opt/usr/apps/com.myStubCompany.testTizen/lib/libtizennative.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I/Unity   (18506): DllNotFoundException: /opt/usr/apps/com.myStubCompany.testTizen/lib/libtizennative.so
```

Ok, I'll look at the path and figure out what's wrong:

```
/opt/usr/apps/com.myStubCompany.testTizen/lib/libtizennative.so
```

Ok, then I'll check if there is the right lib in that folder...

[image]

There is. And yet, errors. (all the other libs were a pitiful attempt to try out every "with lib" "without lib" "with .so" ... combination).

Please... help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by myself:

The main problem was that Tizen usually runs on ARM devices, and *still* the Tizen IDE defaults to x86 compiling.

I switched that back to Arm, and everything goes just fine.